# How to fix: TypeError: item "is undefined"?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I use an `http.get` call to fetch a JSON object from a back-end server, and am trying to retrieve data from the object, but I'm getting "TypeError: obj.attr is undefined". (Note: I've verified that the JSON object is being sent/received without any problems, and is in the format expected). How should I reference specific fields in the object to avoid the error above?

Back-end object data model (from Express `users_controller.js`):

```
exports.user_create_get = function(req, res, next) {
    var authObj = new Auth({
        dateEffective: {value: moment(Date.now()), attr: {hidden: true}},
        username: {value: '', attr: {hidden: false, label: "Username: "}},
        password: {value: '', attr: {hidden: false, label: "Password: "}},
        mainEmail: {value: '', attr: {hidden: false, label: "Email: "}}
    });
    var user = new UserObj({
        authData: [authObj] })
      res.json(user);
};
```

Front-end Angular code to consume the data (`app.component.ts`):

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.member.getMemberForm().subscribe((data)=>{
      this.keys = Object.keys(data["authData"][0]);
      this.keys.forEach(key => {
        let obj = data["authData"][0][key];
        console.log("Key: " + key + "; " +   
          obj["attr"]["label"]);           // <--- ERROR OCCURS HERE
      });
      if (this.data) this.got_data = true; 
    });
```

Here is the stringified JSON Object:

```
{ "_id": "5ced5e4e7da71157709ef1a6", 
    "authData": [ { "_id": "5ced5e4e7da71157709ef1a5", 
        "dateEffective": { "value": 1559060046775, 
            "attr": { "hidden": true, "label": "Date: " } }, 
        "username": { "value": "", 
            "attr": { "hidden": false, "label": "Username: " } }, 
        "password": { "value": "", 
            "attr": { "hidden": false, "label": "Password: " } }, 
        "mainEmail": { "value": "", 
            "attr": { "hidden": false, "label": "Email: " } } } ] 
}
```

Comment: `let obj = data["authData"][0][key];` can you console `obj` and show what is coming

Comment: Have you tried using a breakpoint and examining `obj` at that point? Or just log `obj`?

Comment: the `data` after **subscription** is correct ? try to console it

Comment: your dateEffective has NO attr.label dateEffective:{value:..attr:{hidden:... **label:???** } but why are you not using obj.attr.label?

Comment: Many thanks. I added the `label` attribute to `dateEffective`, and also tried using `obj.attr.label` notation, but still get error. 

I also added the stringified JSON object as above into the original post.

Comment: OK. Figured it out . . . Super N00b mistake! . . . The "_id" field has no `attr` key . . .