# How to use map on json response returned by a REST API with ReactJs

Tags: json, reactjs

I've a json. The only thing I want is `title` from the json.

```
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Bike Servicing System",
      "language": "JavaFX",
      "requires": "JDK 8"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Air Traffic Controller",
      "language": "JavaFX",
      "requires": "JDK 8"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Program Counter",
      "language": "JavaFX",
      "requires": "JDK 8"
    }
  ],
  "profile": {
    "name": "typicode"
  }
}
```

I am using `fetch` and `componentDidMount`. I want to do it musing `map` method to iterate through. Though I don't need `<ul>` and `<li>` tags really. I will remove them later. My React code is

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ProjectStack extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoaded: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://my-json-server.typicode.com/tmtanzeel/json-server/projects/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: json.projects
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    var { isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    var i=0;
    if (!isLoaded) return <div>Loading...</div>;
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
        {
          items.map(item => (
            <li key={item[i++].id}>
              Projects: {item[i++].title}
            </li>
          ))
        }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProjectStack;
```

Apparently, there is something that I don't know because I am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnWzC.png) error.

PS: [This question is different from mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56345682/how-to-fix-typeerror-item-is-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON of the URL you are fetching is this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Bike Servicing System",
    "language": "JavaFX",
    "requires": "JDK 8"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Air Traffic Controller",
    "language": "JavaFX",
    "requires": "JDK 8"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Program Counter",
    "language": "JavaFX",
    "requires": "JDK 8"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Dove Tail",
    "language": "JavaFX",
    "requires": "JDK 8"
  }
]
```

So for correctly set the data in the state you need to:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://my-json-server.typicode.com/tmtanzeel/json-server/projects/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: json
        });
      });
  }
```

Besides correcting the error they have already told you related the map loop.

Comment: Oh. I did not realize the square brackets in the start and end of json. Thanks. But I want to know why only `items: json` and not `items: json.projects`.

Comment: `res.json()` will retrieve the JSON provided by the URL you are fetching. The JSON provided is an array that when the promise is resolved in the `then` is assigned to `json` variable, not in `json.projects` as you thought.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 mistakes from your code.

The first one is you didn't check the response data.

```
fetch("http://my-json-server.typicode.com/tmtanzeel/json-server/projects/")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          console.log(json); // it is an Array not object.
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: json
          });
        });
```

And the second is you didn't use the `map()` properly.

```
/*{
  items.map(item => (
    <li key={item[i++].id}>
      Projects: {item[i++].title}
    </li>
  ))
}*/
// items has objects, so you should use map() like this.
{
  items.map(item => (
    <li key={item.id}>
      Projects: {item.title}
    </li>
  ))
}
```

The below code is one way to achieve what you want.

```js
class ProjectStack extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        items: [],
        isLoaded: false
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      fetch("http://my-json-server.typicode.com/tmtanzeel/json-server/projects/")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          console.log(json);
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: json
          });
        });
    }

    render() {
      const {
        isLoaded,
        items
      } = this.state;
      console.log(items);
      if (!isLoaded) return ( < div > Loading... < /div>);
        return ( <
          div >
          <
          ul > {
            items.map(item => ( <
              li key = {
                item.id
              } > Projects: {
                item.title
              } < /li>
            ))
          } <
          /ul> <
          /div>
        );
      }
    }
    ReactDOM.render( <
      ProjectStack / > , document.getElementById('root')
    )
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```